# Nginx proxy not working

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy

I have a basic Nginx configuration for a Node API and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

My Nginx file looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
   worker_connections 768;
   multi_accept on;
}

http {

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
   #    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and then inside my /etc/nginx/conf.d/ I have a proxy.conf that looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name [domain_name];

  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';

  location / {
    proxy_pass [client_endpoint]
  }

  location /api {
    add_header Allow 'POST, GET, PUT';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    proxy_pass http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3005;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  }
}
```

The proxy from location "/" works fine, but trying to proxy to another port on the server it times out because it cannot reach it, or it will give me a 403 error. I have tried using the IP address and localhost. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The `/` location block is working and the `/api` location is not. I am trying to proxy the `/api` location to port 3005 on the server. Do I need to proxy to localhost or do I need to proxy to the IP/port of my server? I have tried both so I assume there is an issue with my syntax. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: (1) which location block is giving you problems? `/` or `/api`?  (2) You are trying to access port 3005 on localhost?  Could you be more explicit about what your question is?  It didn’t make much sense to me as an outside reader.

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify. Hopefully that makes more sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I usually do for node/nginx:

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:3005;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
  . . . 

  location /api {
    add_header Allow 'POST, GET, PUT';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    proxy_set_header        Connection "";
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://nodejs;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It turned out to not be Nginx related. I enabled TCP traffic on my AWS EC2 instance and the proxy worked.

Comment: where did you do it exactly in ec2 settings?

Comment: In the EC2 Security group

Comment: Did you do it for outbound traffic or inbound or all?